# Why does classifier chain ask for at least 2 classes, when I have it

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

I'm using Classifier Chain with logistic regression and when i try to use fit, i get

> This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1

but I'm pretty sure I have two classes in my data,
this is my X_test

```
<5825x2000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 219990 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

and i have this as my y_train

```
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0]])
```

and this is the part I'm trying to run

```
cc_clf = ClassifierChain(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=1, dual=False, solver='liblinear'))
cc_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
cc_y_pred = cc_clf.predict(X_test)
```

Am i using the classifier chain incorrectly? When I pass in the same data into one vs rest, it works.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifier1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Your `y_train` has an interesting shape. How it should be understood? It looks like one-hot encoding if not for the fact that there are multiple `1` per row.